# Cannot Connect to SQL Server in Parrot OS (No directory in /var/run)

Tags: mysql, apache

I'm trying to set up Damn Vulnerable Web Application on an Apache2 server on Parrot OS.
I've gotten to the DVWA Set-Up page but there's a problem with connecting to the DB. DVWA tells me:

*Database Error #2002: Connection refused.*

I also cannot use mysql to interact with the DB as per this error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL Server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

One problem is that /var/run/mysqld **doesn't exist**. I have no idea what to do about that.
I tried installing mysql-server through the repo but it doesn't seem to work on Parrot OS.
What's this Error 2002 and could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `sudo apt install mariadb-client mariadb-server`
Had the same issue with parrot after upgrade, this solved mine.